# AutoIT user macro to emit the current script name

Tags: macros, autoit, defined

In my #include files, I want to output debug messages that include the line number and the script name, but while the @ScriptLineNumber macro emits the line number of the #include file it's in, there is no way to emit the current file's filename.  I would like to define a user macro something like @ThisScriptName in a debug message like this:

_DebugOut("+++:" & @ThisScriptName & ":" & @ScriptLineNumber & ": some text")

The output would look something like this:

+++:SampleIncludedFile.au3:127: some text

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this so that it gives the included file name using any of the macros available.

The easiest alternative method is to use a variable that is overwritten at the top of each include file.

ExampleScript.au3:

```
#include "ExampleInclude.au3"

Global $ThisScriptName = "ExampleScript"

ConsoleWrite("Hello From: " & $ThisScriptName & @LF)
```

ExampleInclude.au3:

```
; #include <...>

Global $ThisScriptName = "ExampleInclude"

ConsoleWrite("Hello From: " & $ThisScriptName & @LF)
```

With this approach it is important that the variable is defined *after* the other files you are including.

Other alternatives could be using a preprocessor, either writing one yourself or using one of the various ones others have written already. This could be as simple as just replacing every occurrence of @ThisScriptName with the string version of the file.

Comment: I think a preprocessor would be what I want.  I googled around and could not find a tutorial for how to add/call a preprocessor.  Does anyone know how to hook a preprocessor to the build/compile?

Comment: https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/133808-autoit-with-c-preprocessor/

Comment: Also, the "Global $ThisScriptName = blablabla" won't work because it can only be declared once, not several times as suggested.

Comment: @user1588174-Andy Please at least do me the honour of executing the example I included before making a definite statement like that. It works, and always has done. AutoIt allows redeclaring of variables within the same scope.

Comment: I always put the following directive in all of my scripts and UDFs:
#AutoIt3Wrapper_Au3Check_Parameters=-d -w 3
This directive says to check for duplicate variable names.  Without this very important check, I could inadvertently add multiple definitions of variables.

Comment: When I put this directive in your example scripts, the compile fails.

Comment: Did you all quit on me?

Note that '@scriptLineNumber' emits the line number in the local script.
But '@scriptName' emits the main script's filename, not the local script's filename.